# cryptsetup luksOpen key-file does not work

Tags: disk-encryption, luks

I am getting "*No key available with this passphrase.*" when trying:

`sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdc storage --key-file=/path/to/keyfile`

The `/path/to/keyfile` file contains just the passphrase in plain text.

If I enter *the same* passphrase when asked interactively:

`sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdc storage`

then it works.

Why would `--key-file` not work in this case? This is Ubuntu 14.04 @ Linux 3.13.0-68.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you have a trailing newline at the end of your keyfile. This will be used as part of the key so you will need to remove it.

You might try

```
perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' /path/to/file
```

to remove it. e.g.

A keyfile with text

```
fred\n
```

We can use `od` to see the contents of the file

```
od -x keyfile
0000000 7266 6465 000a
0000005
```

then after the perl script is run on it

```
od -x keyfile
0000000 7266 6465
0000004
```

Comment: Thank you!
I actually tried to remove any possible trailing newlines using `nano` editor and Delete / Backspace keys, but apparently some sort of extra space character was still there.

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted the use of `--key-file`. The key file is a file with data (usually random data) that is used to unlock the medium, not a file where a password is stored in plain text.

Thus, you would create a key-file then add that key-file as a key to unlock the medium. Then, you need to keep that key-file safe, to secure your encrypted medium.
One way to generate and add a key-file can be found here:
[HowToForge instruction](https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile)

Comment: Well, plain text is also data.